# Gerenciar session como array

Tags: php, array, session

Queria saber se existe alguma forma de eu salvar dois valores numa mesma variável session como se fosse um array, pois quero que ao clicar no botão "salvar capitulo" da imagem, seja salvo tanto o valor do input text como do  elemento wysiwyg, eu tentei fazer salvar assim:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $titulo  = isset($_POST['titulo']) ? $_POST['titulo'] : '';
    $paragrafo  = isset($_POST['valor_paragrafo']) ? $_POST['valor_paragrafo'] : '';
    $p = $_GET['p'];
    $_SESSION[$p][0] = $titulo;  //aqui salvaria os valores na session
    $_SESSION[$p][1] = $paragrafo;
?>
```

só que quando vou exibir na tela, se eu salvo dessa forma, na tela na hora que vou exibir, aparece só a letra relativa ao indice que coloquei no session ao inves de todo o texto.
código pra exibir na tela os valores:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#paragrafo").Editor();
  $('#paragrafo').Editor('setText', '<?=addslashes($_SESSION["$p"][1])?>');
  $('#titulo').val('<?=($_SESSION["$p"][0])?>');
});
```

os posts do primeiro código php chegam desse html e javascript:

```
function Envia_Form(valor, arquivo, chooser, target){  //valor do chooser: 0 = faz submit com refresh na pagina |  1 = sem refresh na pagina
  $("#valor_paragrafo").val(valor);
  if(chooser == 0){
    $("#form").attr("action",arquivo);
    if(target != ''){
      $("#form").prop("target", target);
    }
    document.form.submit();
  } else if(chooser == 1){
    $.post(
      arquivo,  
      $('#form').serialize(),
      function( data ){
      }
    );
  }
}

<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="proc.php">
    <div class="titulo">TÍTULO
        <input type="text" class="titulo-input" name="titulo" id="titulo" placeholder="Digite o texto">
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="paragrafo" name="paragrafo"></div>
          <input type="hidden" id="valor_paragrafo" name="valor_paragrafo" />
        </div>
    <p>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Salvar Capítulo" onclick="Envia_Form($('#paragrafo').Editor('getText'), 'salva_paragrafo.php?p=<?=$p?>', 1);" />
       <input type="button" value="Gerar PDF" onclick="Envia_Form($('#paragrafo').Editor('getText'), 'proc.php', 0, '_blank');" />
   </p>
```

o sistema:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, o **$_SESSION** é uma variável **SUPERGLOBAL** e permite que você adicione arrays multimensionais.

```
<?php
#inicia a sessão
session_start();

#atribui as sessões
$_SESSION['aula']['video']  = $video;
$_SESSION['aula']['resumo']  = $resumo;
$_SESSION['aula']['descricao']   = $descricao;

#destroi todas as sessões
session_destroy();

?>
```

Analisando teu código, a parte do **PHP** e do **JQUERY** ta ok. Notei que você ta pegando o get e não tá tratando. SESSION não tem índice numerado se o teu **$_GET['p']**, for numero vai dar erro ([vide documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php)).

Cara só para desencargo, muda:

```
$('#paragrafo').Editor('setText', '<?=addslashes($_SESSION["$p"][10])?>');
```

para

```
$('#paragrafo').Editor('setText', '<?=addslashes($_SESSION["$p"][1])?>');
```

e testa se rodar é o que notei de errado.

Comment: mas o que eu precisaria tratar do get? esse indice de 10 pra 1 eu tinha trocado de proposito pra ver se mudava o valor que aparecia nos campos html, e realmente mudou, só que continuo aparecendo uma unica letra :/

Comment: `session_destroy` é obsoleto, prefira fazer algo como: `$_SESSION['aula'] = NULL;`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento por que o session_destroy  é obsoleto? não seria o session_unset o obsoleto??

Comment: @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo perdão me confundi, o problema é que `session_destroy`, o problema dele é que ele vai destruir variáveis além de `$_SESSION['aula']`, o que pode afetar outras funcionalidades do sistema, o melhor caminho é o `$_SESSION['aula'] = NULL;`, prefira usar o `session_destroy` se realmente tem certeza do que esta fazendo.

Comment: ah sim, no sistema eu só to usando o session_destroy quando o usuario clicar em "sair", sim, tem um sistema de login também nesse sistema

Comment: @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo mas é isso que estou dizendo, os session_destroy vai eliminar tudo daquela sessão, se tiver outros dados de outras aplicações que não precisam estar logados pra funcionar eles também serão removidos, resumindo pode usar, mas só quando realmente necessário. O recomendavel é usar `$_SESSION['aula'] = NULL;` e depois verificar com `if (empty($_SESSION['aula']) === false) { ... }` se esta logado.

Comment: E aí deu certo?